# Is it possible to get value from listview and forward it to DataGridView in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, listview, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that gets information from MySQL database. I also have a ListView that also gets values from MySQL database.

In the DataGridView I can see all available employees and other info about them. In Listview I can see just the names of the employees. I have assigned EmployeeID as Value Member.

Is it possible to do so, that if I click on one of the names in ListView then in DataGridView it will show only information about this employee?

Comment: Do you mean ListBox and not ListView?

Comment: Most likely you should set a Filter on the DataView of the DGV. To help to do that we would need to know more details / see the code. Have you mixed up the two controls, btw? Is seems more logical to click on one row in the DGV to restrict the ListView on that employee..

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible
in the `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged` Event add the code to filter the datagridview
if you have the datatable of the datagrid you can do this :

```
   DataView dv = new DataView(yourDatatable);
    dv.RowFilter = "EmployeeID = " + ListView.SelectedValue;
   datagridview.Datasource = dv;
```